# flip scroll when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

We need advice on how to do what would happen with normal scrolling of the page (with a wheel, or in a mob with a finger) after the block has been screwed up to the top of the screen, it began to scroll horizontally and after the edge of the block is reached, the standard scroll continues, respectively, if the scroll goes up, then that's it in reverse order. (There may be several such blocks on a page)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.simple {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #1f69c0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}


.simple2 {
    height: 400px;
    background: #EEAA07;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}
.simple3 {
    height: 400px;
    background: #07eed9;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
}

.outer {
    height: 150px;
    background: #7b8e39;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 100px;
    display: flex;
}

.cube {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple"></div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="cube">1</div>
        <div class="cube">2</div>
        <div class="cube">3</div>
        <div class="cube">4</div>
        <div class="cube">5</div>
        <div class="cube">6</div>
        <div class="cube">7</div>
        <div class="cube">8</div>
        <div class="cube">9</div>
        <div class="cube">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="simple2"></div>
<div class="simple3"></div>
```

Here is an approximate structure, until block 2 has scrolled to the end, block 3 should be visible and after 2 has scrolled horizontally to the end, the standard scroll will continue

PS Here is an example (https://horizontalscrolling.wpdemos.net/horizontal-scrolling/) of how scrolling should work, although there can be more than 1 block on one screen

Answer (score 0):

This technique needs to use javascript called "GSAP" which is a high-performance javascript animation library.

I found a similar animation that you were looking for.

Hopefully, this will help :)

```js
//https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/e72106811a34efcccff91a03568cc790.js?v=3

class SmoothScroll {
  constructor(options) {
    
    this.endThreshold = 0.05;
    this.requestId = null;
    this.maxDepth = 10;
    this.viewHeight = 0;
    this.halfViewHeight = 0;
    this.maxDistance = 0;
    this.viewWidth = 0;
    this.halfViewWidth = 0;
    this.maxDistanceWidth = 0;
    this.scrollHeight = 0;
    this.endScroll = 0;
    this.returnCurrentScroll = 0;
    this.currentScroll = 0;
    this.scrollTransform = 0;
    this.horizontalScroll = 0;
    this.resizeRequest = 1;
    this.scrollRequest = 0;
    this.scrollItems = [];
    this.lastTime = -1;
    this.maxElapsedMS = 100;
    this.targetFPMS = 0.06;

    // this.scrollBody = options.scrollBody;
    // this.scrollSpacer = options.scrollSpacer;

    this.target = options.target;

    this.scrollEase = options.scrollEase != null ? options.scrollEase : 0.1;
    this.maxOffset = options.maxOffset != null ? options.maxOffset : 500;

    this.horizontalScrollWrapper = options.horizontalScrollWrapper;

    this.horizontalScrollTarget = options.horizontalScrollTarget;

    this._horziontalSetHeihgt();

    this.childElements = this._childElements();

    this.rectHorStart = this.horizontalScrollWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    this.horzItemStart = {
      top: this.rectHorStart.top,
      bottom: this.rectHorStart.bottom,
      height: this.rectHorStart.height
    }

    this.addItems();

    window.addEventListener("resize", this._onResize);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this._onScroll);
    //this.scrollBody.addEventListener("scroll", this._onScroll);

    this._update();
  }

  _childElements = (event) => {
    const childElementsNode = this.target.querySelectorAll("*[data-color]");
    return childElementsNode;
  }

  _horizonstalScrollRect = (event) => {
    const horzintalRect = this.horizontalScrollTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    return horzintalRect;
  }

  _lastScrollRect = (event) => {
    const lastScrollRect = this.horizontalScrollTarget.lastElementChild.getBoundingClientRect();
    return lastScrollRect;
  }

  _horziontalSetHeihgt = (event) => {
    let horScrHeight = 0;
    if (
      this.horizontalScrollTarget !== null &&
      this.horizontalScrollWrapper !== null
    ) {
      const lastScrollRect = this._lastScrollRect();
      horScrHeight = this.horizontalScrollTarget.scrollWidth - lastScrollRect.width + this._horizonstalScrollRect().height;
      this.horizontalScrollWrapper.style.height = horScrHeight + "px";
    }
  }

  _onResize = (event) => {
    this.resizeRequest++;
    if (!this.requestId) {
      this.lastTime = performance.now();
      this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this._update);
    }
  };

  _onScroll = (event) => {
    this.scrollRequest++;
    if (!this.requestId) {
      this.lastTime = performance.now();
      this.requestId = requestAnimationFrame(this._update);
    }
  };

  _horizonstalScroll = (scrollY,dt) => {
    if (this.horizontalScrollWrapper !== null) {
      const rectHor = this.horizontalScrollWrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
      const lastScrollRect = this._lastScrollRect();

      const itemHor = {
        target: this.horizontalScrollTarget,
        targetRect: this._horizonstalScrollRect(),
        top: rectHor.top,
        bottom: rectHor.bottom + scrollY,
        topScroll: rectHor.top + scrollY,
        horizonstalMove: 0,
      };
      
      itemHor.horizonstalMove += this.currentScroll - this.horzItemStart.top;
      if(scrollY >= this.horzItemStart.top && scrollY <= this.horzItemStart.bottom - itemHor.targetRect.height){  
        itemHor.target.style.position = 'fixed';
        itemHor.target.style.transform = `translate3d(-${itemHor.horizonstalMove}px,0px,0px)`;

        //this._paralaxHorizontal(dt);

        if(lastScrollRect.x <= (lastScrollRect.width/2)){
          this.scrollTransform = this.horzItemStart.bottom - itemHor.targetRect.height;
          itemHor.target.style.top = this.horzItemStart.bottom - itemHor.targetRect.height+'px';
        }else {
          this.scrollTransform = this.horzItemStart.top;
          itemHor.target.style.top = this.horzItemStart.top+'px';
        }
      }
    }
  };

  _changeColorBody = (event) => {

    if(this.childElements.length > 0){
      this.childElements.forEach(child => {
        const wrapper = document.querySelector('.change_color_page');
        const childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
        const childAttr = child.getAttribute('data-color');

        if(childRect.y <= this.halfViewHeight && childRect.bottom >= this.halfViewHeight){
          if(childAttr == "off_white"){
            if(!document.body.classList.contains('white')){
              document.body.classList.add('white');
            }
            if(!wrapper.classList.contains('white')){
              wrapper.classList.add('white');
            }
          }else if(childAttr == "dark"){
            if(document.body.classList.contains('white')){
              document.body.classList.remove('white');
            }
            if(wrapper.classList.contains('white')){
              wrapper.classList.remove('white');
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }

  }

  _update = (currentTime = performance.now()) => {
    let elapsedMS = currentTime - this.lastTime;

    if (elapsedMS > this.maxElapsedMS) {
      elapsedMS = this.maxElapsedMS;
    }

    const deltaTime = elapsedMS * this.targetFPMS;
    const dt = 1 - Math.pow(1 - this.scrollEase, deltaTime);

    const resized = this.resizeRequest > 0;
    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
    //const scrollY = this.scrollBody.scrollTop;

    if (resized) {
      this._horziontalSetHeihgt();
      const height = this.target.clientHeight;
      document.body.style.height = height + "px";
      //this.scrollSpacer.style.height = height + "px";
      this.scrollHeight = height;
      this.viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
      this.halfViewHeight = this.viewHeight / 2;
      this.maxDistance = this.viewHeight * 2;
      this.resizeRequest = 0;
      this.viewWidth = window.innerWidth;
      this.halfViewWidth = this.viewWidth / 2;
      this.maxDistanceWidth = this.viewWidth * 2;
    }

    this.endScroll = scrollY;
    // this.scrollTransform += (scrollY - this.scrollTransform) * this.scrollEase;
    this.scrollTransform += (scrollY - this.scrollTransform) * dt;
    this.currentScroll += (scrollY - this.currentScroll) * dt;

    if (Math.abs(scrollY - this.currentScroll) < this.endThreshold || resized) {
      this.currentScroll = scrollY;
      this.scrollRequest = 0;
    }

    if (
      Math.abs(scrollY - this.scrollTransform) < this.endThreshold ||
      resized
    ) {
      this.scrollTransform = scrollY;
      this.scrollRequest = 0;
    }

    ///change color section
    this._changeColorBody();

    ///horizontal scroll
    this._horizonstalScroll(this.currentScroll,dt);

    // const scrollOrigin = scrollY + this.halfViewHeight;
    const scrollOrigin = this.currentScroll + this.viewHeight;

    this.target.style.transform = `translate3d(0px,-${this.scrollTransform}px,0px)`;

    //items
    for (let i = 0; i < this.scrollItems.length; i++) {
      const item = this.scrollItems[i];

      const distance = scrollOrigin - item.top;
      const offsetRatio = distance / this.maxDistance;

      item.endOffset = Math.round(
        this.maxOffset * item.depthRatio * offsetRatio
      );

      if (Math.abs(item.endOffset - item.currentOffset < this.endThreshold)) {
        item.currentOffset = item.endOffset;
      } else {
        // item.currentOffset += (item.endOffset - item.currentOffset) * this.scrollEase;
        item.currentOffset += (item.endOffset - item.currentOffset) * dt;
      }
      if(item.direction == "y"){
        item.target.style.transform = `translate3d(0px,${item.currentOffset}px,0px)`;
      }else if(item.direction == "x"){
        item.target.style.transform = `translate3d(${item.currentOffset}px,0px,0px)`;
      }
    }

    this.lastTime = currentTime;

    this.requestId =
      this.scrollRequest > 0 ? requestAnimationFrame(this._update) : null;
  };

  addItems() {
    this.scrollItems = [];
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-depth]");
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      const element = elements[i];
      const depth = +element.getAttribute("data-depth");
      const direction_item = element.getAttribute("data-direction");
      const rect_item = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const item = {
        rect: rect_item,
        target: element,
        top: rect_item.top + window.pageYOffset,
        //top: rect_item.top + this.scrollBody.scrollTop,
        depth: depth,
        depthRatio: depth / this.maxDepth,
        currentOffset: 0,
        endOffset: 0,
        direction: direction_item
      };
      this.scrollItems.push(item);
    }
    return this;
  }

  currentScrollReturn() {
    return this.currentScroll;
  }
}

document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  "--scrollbar-size",
  getScrollbarSize() + "px"
);

var scroller = new SmoothScroll({
  // scrollBody: document.querySelector(".scroll-content"),
  // scrollSpacer: document.querySelector(".spacer"),
  target: document.querySelector(".scroll-container"), // element container to scroll
  scrollEase: 0.05,
  horizontalScrollWrapper: document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll-wrapper"),
  horizontalScrollTarget: document.querySelector(".horizontal-scroll")
});

function getScrollbarSize() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("scrollbar-test");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  var size = div.offsetWidth - div.scrollWidth;
  document.body.removeChild(div);
  return size;
}
```

```css
$white: #fbe8ee;
$black: #0a0a0a;

:root {
  --scrollbar-size: 0px;
}

*, :after, :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  
}

.viewport {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  *:not(.change_color_page) {
    color: $white;
    transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out, border-color 0.5s ease;
    border-color: $white;
  }
  &.white {
    *:not(.change_color_page) {
      color: $black;
      transition: color 0.5s ease-in-out, border-color 0.5s ease;
      border-color: $black;
    }
  }
}

.change_color_page {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: $black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  &.white {
    background-color: $white;
  }
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  background-color: $white;
  &.white {
    background-color: $black;
  }
}

.scrollbar-test {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -99999px;
  left: -99999px;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.fixed-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: var(--scrollbar-size, 0px);
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.scroll-container {  
  position: absolute;  
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.spacer {
  background: transparent;
}

.single-item {
  flex: 0 0 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  &.left {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  p {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
}

.horizontal-scroll-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.horizontal-scroll {
  display: flex;
}

.horizontal-scroll .single-item {
  flex: 0 0 100vw;
  p {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="change_color_page"></div>
    <header></header>
    <div class="viewport">
        <div class="scroll-container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="single-item active" data-color="off_white">
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item" data-color="dark">
                    <p data-depth="-7" data-direction="y">2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item" data-color="off_white">
                    <p class="item_to_move">3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item" data-color="dark">
                    <p data-depth="-3" data-direction="y">4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item" data-color="off_white">
                    <p data-depth="-3" data-direction="y">5</p>
                </div>
                <div class="horizontal-scroll-wrapper" data-color="dark">
                    <div class="horizontal-scroll">
                        <div class="single-item">
                            <p><span data-depth-hor="-3" data-direction="left">6</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-item">
                            <p><span data-depth-hor="-3" data-direction="left">7</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-item">
                            <p><span data-depth-hor="-3" data-direction="left">8</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-item">
                            <p><span data-depth-hor="-3" data-direction="left">9</span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-item">
                            <p><span data-depth-hor="-3" data-direction="left">10</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item" data-color="off_white">
                    <p data-depth="-3" data-direction="y">11</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item" data-color="dark">
                    <p data-depth="-3" data-direction="y">12</p>
                </div>
                <div class="single-item left" data-color="off_white">
                    <p data-depth="15" data-direction="x">13</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

source code from: https://codepen.io/duty47/pen/vYYEgam

Comment: I forgot to mention, for more information just search for GSAP horizontal/vertical scroll

Comment: This is not quite right, the problem is that I have a block height of 200px and a screen height of 500, well, that's figurative. The ideal option is, upon reaching the top block, to block the standard window scrolling and horizontally to the desired block, but I can't stop the page scrolling. you also need it to work on mobile devices